# Shift label below arrow in \path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just want to shift the the label of $v_m\pahse{j-45}$ to below the arrow, any idea how can i do that?

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{steinmetz}   
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,    % new
                quotes}                 % new
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
%\usepackage{gensymb} % better is to use siunitx

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=west,
              angle radius = 8mm, angle eccentricity=1},
arr/.style = {cap=round,-Straight Barb},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, sloped},
every label/.style       = {inner sep=1pt},
                        ]
% axis
\draw[arr]  (-2.7,0)--(3.6,0)   node[below] {$\Re$}; % x axis
\draw[arr]  (0,-2.7)--(0,3.6) node[left]  {$\Im$}; % y axis
% circle
\draw       (0,0) circle (3.25cm);
% defining radius points
\node (n1) [dot,] at (-45:3.25) {};
\node (n2) [dot,]   at (45:3.25) {};
\node (n3) [dot,] at ( 0:3.25) {};
% vector
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path[draw=black, ultra thick, arr] 
    (O) to ["$\,\,\quad \quad V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(45^{\circ})}$"]  (n2.center);
\path[draw=lava, ultra thick, arr] 
    (O) to ["$\,\,\quad \quad V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(-45^{\circ})}$"]  (n1.center);
    \path[draw=myblue, ultra thick, arr] 
    (O) to ["$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\quad V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(0^{\circ})}$"]  (n3.center);
    
    
% angle
\pic [ang, "$45^{\circ}$"] {angle = n3--O--n2};
\pic [ang, "$-45^{\circ}$"] {angle = n1--O--n3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your 45 degrees are not correctly placed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the [TiKZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TiKZ) `quotes` library. Looking at page 254 of the [TiKZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TiKZ) manual we see:

> Once loaded, inside the options of a node command you may also provide strings of the following form:
> "⟨text⟩"⟨options⟩

So all that you need to do is add the word "below" to the node specifications. This produces:

[image]

I have also taken the liberty of replacing `\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\quad` in the MWE with `above right`. Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{steinmetz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,    % new
                quotes}                 % new
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=west,
              angle radius = 8mm, angle eccentricity=1},
arr/.style = {cap=round,-Straight Barb},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, sloped},
every label/.style       = {inner sep=1pt},
                        ]
% axis
\draw[arr]  (-2.7,0)--(3.6,0)   node[below] {$\Re$}; % x axis
\draw[arr]  (0,-2.7)--(0,3.6) node[left]  {$\Im$}; % y axis
% circle
\draw       (0,0) circle (3.25cm);
% defining radius points
\node (n1) [dot,] at (-45:3.25) {};
\node (n2) [dot,]   at (45:3.25) {};
\node (n3) [dot,] at ( 0:3.25) {};
% vector
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path[draw=black, ultra thick, arr]
    (O) to ["$\,\,\quad \quad V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(45^{\circ})}$"]  (n2.center);
\path[draw=lava, ultra thick, arr]
    (O) to ["$\,\,\quad \quad V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(-45^{\circ})}$" below]  (n1.center);
\path[draw=myblue, ultra thick, arr]
    (O) to ["$V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(0^{\circ})}$" above right]  (n3.center);

% angle
\pic [ang, "$45^{\circ}$"] {angle = n3--O--n2};
\pic [ang, "$-45^{\circ}$"] {angle = n1--O--n3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace existing path with

```
\path[draw=lava, ultra thick, arr] 
    (O) to node [below,sloped]{$V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(-45^{\circ})}$}  (n1.center);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One more solution, using `quote` syntax for positioning labels on desired side of path (vector in your case) and `siunitx` for writing of angles values:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,   
                quotes}                
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{siunitx}     % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=west,
              angle radius = 8mm, angle eccentricity=1,
              font=\footnotesize},  % <--- added
arr/.style = {cap=round,-Straight Barb},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, sloped},
every label/.style       = {inner sep=1pt},
                        ]
% axis
\draw[arr]  (-3.4,0)--(3.6,0) node[below] {$\Re$}; % changed
\draw[arr]  (0,-3.4)--(0,3.6) node[left]  {$\Im$}; % changed
% circle
\draw       (0,0) circle (3.25cm);
% defining radius points
\node (n1) [dot,] at (-45:3.25) {};
\node (n2) [dot,] at ( 45:3.25) {};
\node (n3) [dot,] at (  0:3.25) {};
% vector
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path[draw=black, ultra thick, arr]
    (O) to ["$V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(\SI{45}{\degree})}$"]  (n2.center);
\path[draw=lava, ultra thick, arr]
    (O) to ["$V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(\SI{-45}{\degree})}$" ']  (n1.center); % <--- observe added '
    \path[draw=myblue, ultra thick, arr]
    (O) to [pos=0.7,"$ V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(\SI{0}{\degree})}$" ]  (n3.center);

% angle
\pic [ang, "\SI{45}{\degree}"] {angle = n3--O--n2};
\pic [ang, "\SI{-45}{\degree}"] {angle = n1--O--n3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In comparison to your MWE the following changes are made in above MWE:

- for  positioning of label is used shortens `'` for option `swap`, which push label on opposite side of vector:

```
(O) to ["$V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(\SI{-45}{\degree})}$" swap]
```

or slightly shorter

```
(O) to ["$V_m\mathrm{e}^{j(\SI{-45}{\degree})}$" ']
```

- axis are prolonged that can cross the circle
- for label positioning is used option `pos=...` whih can moveposition of label from middle of path to desired point on the path
- for better readable the angle labels is reduced to `\footnotesize`

Comment: @Diana, see edited answer. Now is added explanation. Can be helpful.